# Python: How to use recursion and basic os methods to retrieve the path to the largest file in a directory

Tags: python

so recently I was tasked upon coding a method called getLargestFile that takes in a path and returns a string with all the folders/file name at the end.

Example:

```
assert(findLargestFile("sampleFiles/folderA") == "sampleFiles/folderA/folderC/giftwrap.txt"
```

File layout: [First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGBQr.png) [Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJaep.png) [Third Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuO4r.png)

I am not allowed to use os.walk nor am I allowed to call os.path.getsize on a single file more than once, also, I cannot use listFiles to list all the files in one place. (Also just basic os methods)

My code currently is below:

```
def findLargestFile(path):
    findLargestFileHelper(path)


def findLargestFileHelper(path, size=0, pathToLargest=""):
    if (os.path.isdir(path) == False):
        if os.path.getsize(path) > size:
            size = os.path.getsize(path)
            pathToLargest = os.path.dirname(path) + os.path.basename(path)
    else:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            findLargestFileHelper(path + "/" + filename)
    
    return pathToLargest
```

I know there are for sure errors in the code, but I am just not too sure about the general concept of this file recursion, and am not sure why when I call:

`findLargestFile("sampleFiles/folderA")`, it returns none.

If someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You’re not returning anything when you recursively call `findLargestFileHelper(path + "/" + filename)`.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, what I was trying to do there was to call this helper again till I find a file instead of a folder, and once I do so, I can use os.path.dirname / os.path.basename to log the file route, and at the end return the largest one.